# ROPSTEN: Duplicate Blocks adding transactions using Geth Real-Time Event API

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, blocks, websocket

I'm using the [Geth Real-Time Event](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/pubsub) to get the new blocks via web-socket and there's a subscription called **"newHeads"** for that propose.

The thing is sometimes the socket returns a duplicate block with different content. Why?

I'm using "Simple Websocket Client" extension for the socket.

Look at the attached picture and check block number **"0x9073d7"**

[image]

This is a diff of the content of both blocks: https://www.diffchecker.com/2UUt8n6H

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: We suppose that it was a fork, but I can't answer your previous question. I suppose you need to wait for the following block to check which one has the same hash as the "parentHash".

Answer (score 1):

It was a fork that was later replaced by the main chain. Fork may be more than one block.

Comment: But how can we know at the time of receiving the block that it won't be contained in the canonical chain? Should we just wait for the next block number? Even if we would wait, how could we determine which one of the duplicates will eventually show up on bscscan?